# How to Turn off debug mode in OpenLDAP?

Tags: redhat, openldap, rhel7

I have start open ldap server with log mode from below command

```
slapd -u ldap -g ldap -d 65
```

after that i tried to stop the server and restart again but still i am getting too many log in terminal. Can some one please help me how to start the openldap2.4 in normal mode again?

Please have a look below

```
[root@suredevbana3 ~]# service slapd stop
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl stop  slapd.service
[root@suredevbana3 ~]# systemctl start slapd.service
[root@suredevbana3 ~]# ldapsearch -v -d 63 -W -D 'cn=ldapadm,dc=suredevbana3' -b "" -s base
ldap_initialize( <DEFAULT> )
ldap_create
Enter LDAP Password:
ldap_sasl_bind
ldap_send_initial_request
ldap_new_connection 1 1 0
ldap_int_open_connection
ldap_connect_to_host: TCP localhost:389
ldap_new_socket: 3
ldap_prepare_socket: 3
ldap_connect_to_host: Trying ::1 389
ldap_pvt_connect: fd: 3 tm: -1 async: 0
attempting to connect:
connect success
ldap_open_defconn: successful
ldap_send_server_request
ber_scanf fmt ({it) ber:
ber_dump: buf=0x7f2940d104c0 ptr=0x7f2940d104c0 end=0x7f2940d104f1 len=49
  0000:  30 2f 02 01 01 60 2a 02  01 03 04 1a 63 6e 3d 6c   0/...`*.....cn=l
  0010:  64 61 70 61 64 6d 2c 64  63 3d 73 75 72 65 64 65   dapadm,dc=surede
  0020:  76 62 61 6e 61 33 80 09  6f 73 73 72 64 40 37 36   vbana3..ossrd@76
  0030:  35                                                 5
ber_scanf fmt ({i) ber:
ber_dump: buf=0x7f2940d104c0 ptr=0x7f2940d104c5 end=0x7f2940d104f1 len=44
  0000:  60 2a 02 01 03 04 1a 63  6e 3d 6c 64 61 70 61 64   `*.....cn=ldapad
  0010:  6d 2c 64 63 3d 73 75 72  65 64 65 76 62 61 6e 61   m,dc=suredevbana
  0020:  33 80 09 6f 73 73 72 64  40 37 36 35               3..ossrd@765
ber_flush2: 49 bytes to sd 3
  0000:  30 2f 02 01 01 60 2a 02  01 03 04 1a 63 6e 3d 6c   0/...`*.....cn=l
  0010:  64 61 70 61 64 6d 2c 64  63 3d 73 75 72 65 64 65   dapadm,dc=surede
  0020:  76 62 61 6e 61 33 80 09  6f 73 73 72 64 40 37 36   vbana3..ossrd@76
  0030:  35                                                 5
ldap_write: want=49, written=49
  0000:  30 2f 02 01 01 60 2a 02  01 03 04 1a 63 6e 3d 6c   0/...`*.....cn=l
  0010:  64 61 70 61 64 6d 2c 64  63 3d 73 75 72 65 64 65   dapadm,dc=surede
  0020:  76 62 61 6e 61 33 80 09  6f 73 73 72 64 40 37 36   vbana3..ossrd@76
  0030:  35                                                 5
ldap_result ld 0x7f2940d07820 msgid 1
wait4msg ld 0x7f2940d07820 msgid 1 (infinite timeout)
wait4msg continue ld 0x7f2940d07820 msgid 1 all 1
** ld 0x7f2940d07820 Connections:
* host: localhost  port: 389  (default)
  refcnt: 2  status: Connected
  last used: Tue Nov 28 14:58:22 2017


** ld 0x7f2940d07820 Outstanding Requests:
 * msgid 1,  origid 1, status InProgress
   outstanding referrals 0, parent count 0
  ld 0x7f2940d07820 request count 1 (abandoned 0)
** ld 0x7f2940d07820 Response Queue:
   Empty
  ld 0x7f2940d07820 response count 0
ldap_chkResponseList ld 0x7f2940d07820 msgid 1 all 1
ldap_chkResponseList returns ld 0x7f2940d07820 NULL
ldap_int_select
read1msg: ld 0x7f2940d07820 msgid 1 all 1
ber_get_next
ldap_read: want=8, got=8
  0000:  30 0c 02 01 01 61 07 0a                            0....a..
ldap_read: want=6, got=6
  0000:  01 00 04 00 04 00                                  ......
ber_get_next: tag 0x30 len 12 contents:
ber_dump: buf=0x7f2940d023d0 ptr=0x7f2940d023d0 end=0x7f2940d023dc len=12
  0000:  02 01 01 61 07 0a 01 00  04 00 04 00               ...a........
read1msg: ld 0x7f2940d07820 msgid 1 message type bind
ber_scanf fmt ({eAA) ber:
ber_dump: buf=0x7f2940d023d0 ptr=0x7f2940d023d3 end=0x7f2940d023dc len=9
  0000:  61 07 0a 01 00 04 00 04  00                        a........
read1msg: ld 0x7f2940d07820 0 new referrals
read1msg:  mark request completed, ld 0x7f2940d07820 msgid 1
request done: ld 0x7f2940d07820 msgid 1
res_errno: 0, res_error: <>, res_matched: <>
ldap_free_request (origid 1, msgid 1)
ldap_parse_result
ber_scanf fmt ({iAA) ber:
ber_dump: buf=0x7f2940d023d0 ptr=0x7f2940d023d3 end=0x7f2940d023dc len=9
  0000:  61 07 0a 01 00 04 00 04  00                        a........
ber_scanf fmt (}) ber:
ber_dump: buf=0x7f2940d023d0 ptr=0x7f2940d023dc end=0x7f2940d023dc len=0

ldap_msgfree
filter: (objectclass=*)
requesting: All userApplication attributes
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <> with scope baseObject
# filter: (objectclass=*)
# requesting: ALL
#

ldap_search_ext
put_filter: "(objectclass=*)"
put_filter: simple
put_simple_filter: "objectclass=*"
ldap_build_search_req ATTRS: *
ldap_send_initial_request
ldap_send_server_request
ber_scanf fmt ({it) ber:
ber_dump: buf=0x7f2940d104c0 ptr=0x7f2940d104c0 end=0x7f2940d104e7 len=39
  0000:  30 25 02 01 02 63 20 04  00 0a 01 00 0a 01 00 02   0%...c .........
  0010:  01 00 02 01 00 01 01 00  87 0b 6f 62 6a 65 63 74   ..........object
  0020:  63 6c 61 73 73 30 00                               class0.
ber_scanf fmt ({) ber:
ber_dump: buf=0x7f2940d104c0 ptr=0x7f2940d104c5 end=0x7f2940d104e7 len=34
  0000:  63 20 04 00 0a 01 00 0a  01 00 02 01 00 02 01 00   c ..............
  0010:  01 01 00 87 0b 6f 62 6a  65 63 74 63 6c 61 73 73   .....objectclass
  0020:  30 00                                              0.
ber_flush2: 39 bytes to sd 3
  0000:  30 25 02 01 02 63 20 04  00 0a 01 00 0a 01 00 02   0%...c .........
  0010:  01 00 02 01 00 01 01 00  87 0b 6f 62 6a 65 63 74   ..........object
  0020:  63 6c 61 73 73 30 00                               class0.
ldap_write: want=39, written=39
  0000:  30 25 02 01 02 63 20 04  00 0a 01 00 0a 01 00 02   0%...c .........
  0010:  01 00 02 01 00 01 01 00  87 0b 6f 62 6a 65 63 74   ..........object
  0020:  63 6c 61 73 73 30 00                               class0.
ldap_result ld 0x7f2940d07820 msgid -1
wait4msg ld 0x7f2940d07820 msgid -1 (infinite timeout)
wait4msg continue ld 0x7f2940d07820 msgid -1 all 0
** ld 0x7f2940d07820 Connections:
* host: localhost  port: 389  (default)
  refcnt: 2  status: Connected
  last used: Tue Nov 28 14:58:22 2017


** ld 0x7f2940d07820 Outstanding Requests:
 * msgid 2,  origid 2, status InProgress
   outstanding referrals 0, parent count 0
  ld 0x7f2940d07820 request count 1 (abandoned 0)
** ld 0x7f2940d07820 Response Queue:
   Empty
  ld 0x7f2940d07820 response count 0
ldap_chkResponseList ld 0x7f2940d07820 msgid -1 all 0
ldap_chkResponseList returns ld 0x7f2940d07820 NULL
ldap_int_select
read1msg: ld 0x7f2940d07820 msgid -1 all 0
ber_get_next
ldap_read: want=8, got=8
  0000:  30 30 02 01 02 64 2b 04                            00...d+.
ldap_read: want=42, got=42
  0000:  00 30 27 30 25 04 0b 6f  62 6a 65 63 74 43 6c 61   .0'0%..objectCla
  0010:  73 73 31 16 04 03 74 6f  70 04 0f 4f 70 65 6e 4c   ss1...top..OpenL
  0020:  44 41 50 72 6f 6f 74 44  53 45                     DAProotDSE
ber_get_next: tag 0x30 len 48 contents:
ber_dump: buf=0x7f2940d023d0 ptr=0x7f2940d023d0 end=0x7f2940d02400 len=48
  0000:  02 01 02 64 2b 04 00 30  27 30 25 04 0b 6f 62 6a   ...d+..0'0%..obj
  0010:  65 63 74 43 6c 61 73 73  31 16 04 03 74 6f 70 04   ectClass1...top.
  0020:  0f 4f 70 65 6e 4c 44 41  50 72 6f 6f 74 44 53 45   .OpenLDAProotDSE
read1msg: ld 0x7f2940d07820 msgid 2 message type search-entry
ldap_get_dn_ber
ber_scanf fmt ({ml{) ber:
ber_dump: buf=0x7f2940d023d0 ptr=0x7f2940d023d3 end=0x7f2940d02400 len=45
  0000:  64 2b 04 00 30 27 30 25  04 0b 6f 62 6a 65 63 74   d+..0'0%..object
  0010:  43 6c 61 73 73 31 16 04  03 74 6f 70 04 0f 4f 70   Class1...top..Op
  0020:  65 6e 4c 44 41 50 72 6f  6f 74 44 53 45            enLDAProotDSE
ldap_dn2ufn
ldap_dn_normalize
=> ldap_bv2dn(,0)
=> ldap_dn2bv(64)
#
dn:
ber_scanf fmt ({xx) ber:
ber_dump: buf=0x7f2940d023d0 ptr=0x7f2940d023d3 end=0x7f2940d02400 len=45
  0000:  64 2b 04 00 00 27 30 25  04 0b 6f 62 6a 65 63 74   d+...'0%..object
  0010:  43 6c 61 73 73 31 16 04  03 74 6f 70 04 0f 4f 70   Class1...top..Op
  0020:  65 6e 4c 44 41 50 72 6f  6f 74 44 53 45            enLDAProotDSE
ldap_get_attribute_ber
ber_scanf fmt ({mM}) ber:
ber_dump: buf=0x7f2940d023d0 ptr=0x7f2940d023d9 end=0x7f2940d02400 len=39
  0000:  30 25 04 0b 6f 62 6a 65  63 74 43 6c 61 73 73 31   0%..objectClass1
  0010:  16 04 03 74 6f 70 04 0f  4f 70 65 6e 4c 44 41 50   ...top..OpenLDAP
  0020:  72 6f 6f 74 44 53 45                               rootDSE
objectClass: top
objectClass: OpenLDAProotDSE
ldap_get_attribute_ber
ldap_msgfree
ldap_result ld 0x7f2940d07820 msgid -1
wait4msg ld 0x7f2940d07820 msgid -1 (infinite timeout)
wait4msg continue ld 0x7f2940d07820 msgid -1 all 0
** ld 0x7f2940d07820 Connections:
* host: localhost  port: 389  (default)
  refcnt: 2  status: Connected
  last used: Tue Nov 28 14:58:22 2017


** ld 0x7f2940d07820 Outstanding Requests:
 * msgid 2,  origid 2, status InProgress
   outstanding referrals 0, parent count 0
  ld 0x7f2940d07820 request count 1 (abandoned 0)
** ld 0x7f2940d07820 Response Queue:
   Empty
  ld 0x7f2940d07820 response count 0
ldap_chkResponseList ld 0x7f2940d07820 msgid -1 all 0
ldap_chkResponseList returns ld 0x7f2940d07820 NULL
ldap_int_select
read1msg: ld 0x7f2940d07820 msgid -1 all 0
ber_get_next
ldap_read: want=8, got=8
  0000:  30 0c 02 01 02 65 07 0a                            0....e..
ldap_read: want=6, got=6
  0000:  01 00 04 00 04 00                                  ......
ber_get_next: tag 0x30 len 12 contents:
ber_dump: buf=0x7f2940d077b0 ptr=0x7f2940d077b0 end=0x7f2940d077bc len=12
  0000:  02 01 02 65 07 0a 01 00  04 00 04 00               ...e........
read1msg: ld 0x7f2940d07820 msgid 2 message type search-result
ber_scanf fmt ({eAA) ber:
ber_dump: buf=0x7f2940d077b0 ptr=0x7f2940d077b3 end=0x7f2940d077bc len=9
  0000:  65 07 0a 01 00 04 00 04  00                        e........
read1msg: ld 0x7f2940d07820 0 new referrals
read1msg:  mark request completed, ld 0x7f2940d07820 msgid 2
request done: ld 0x7f2940d07820 msgid 2
res_errno: 0, res_error: <>, res_matched: <>
ldap_free_request (origid 2, msgid 2)

# search result
search: 2
ldap_parse_result
ber_scanf fmt ({iAA) ber:
ber_dump: buf=0x7f2940d077b0 ptr=0x7f2940d077b3 end=0x7f2940d077bc len=9
  0000:  65 07 0a 01 00 04 00 04  00                        e........
ber_scanf fmt (}) ber:
ber_dump: buf=0x7f2940d077b0 ptr=0x7f2940d077bc end=0x7f2940d077bc len=0

ldap_err2string
result: 0 Success
ldap_msgfree

# numResponses: 2
# numEntries: 1
ldap_free_connection 1 1
ldap_send_unbind
ber_flush2: 7 bytes to sd 3
  0000:  30 05 02 01 03 42 00                               0....B.
ldap_write: want=7, written=7
  0000:  30 05 02 01 03 42 00                               0....B.
ldap_free_connection: actually freed
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with configuring OpenLDAP on RedHat, but I can tell you there is no indication in your question that the logging is set to anything in particular on the server side.

You are specifying debug logging in your client, ldapsearch.

**Remove the `-d 63` option from your `ldapsearch` command.**

To see what the server is logging, try `journalctl -u slapd -e` on the server.

Answer (score -1):

You can try with

```
systemctl start slapd.service
```

check your slapd.conf file, sel loglevel 0
refer below site for reference
https://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/slapdconfig.html

Comment: Thanks but i did same after stopping ldap .But still i am seeing too many log.

Comment: check your slapd.conf file, sel loglevel 0
refer below site for reference
https://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/slapdconfig.html

Comment: in the OpenLdap2.4 these setting are little bit different